# Swapping non-adjacent selections in Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I've seen friends do the following on the Macintosh: you've written, say, "*joy and comfort*" and you realize it should be "*comfort and joy*" - on the Mac, you can select both '*comfort*' and '*joy*' and then swap them with a single keyboard shortcut. It's miles faster than cutting '*comfort*', pasting it into the correct position, and then repeating the whole rigmarole with '*joy*'. Especially since, when you've done this, you probably then have to remove a double space on one side of the word '*and*' and insert a missing one the other side.

Since the Word keyboard allows you to store up to 20 selections, it should be easy to swap any two around (especially the two most recent). Alas, it seems, you can't.

Why can't you do this in Word, or can you?